# PHP TRUE or FALSE in OOP in public function with private property

Tags: php, oop, admin

Can someone explain me this code:

```
<?php

class User {

    private $is_admin= false;

    private function has_admin_acces(){
        return $this->is_admin === true;
    }

    public function acces_level() {
        return $this->has_admin_acces()  ? 'Admin': "Standard";
    }    
}

$user = new User();
echo $user->acces_level(); **//returns Standard**
?>
```

Firstly I dont understand this part "? 'Admin': "Standard";" after the function name.

Secondly, why does the function echo Standard  , shouldnt it be Admin , 
because I think the function has_admin_acces() changed the value of $is_admin to true when it gets called.

I hope someone can explain this.

Comment: Look up ternary operator in the manual

Comment: Nothing here is assigning anything except to `return`. `return $this->is_admin === true;` is not setting `is_admin` to true, it is _comparing_ it to true, it is basically acting as an IF statement, it will retun true/false depending on what `is_admin` is set to.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an assignment that changes the value of `is_admin`:

```
return $this->is_admin === true;
```

It's a *comparison*. It's asking, "Is `is_admin` equal to `true`?" The answer to that question is a boolean true or false, which then gets returned. It's the same as doing:

```
if ($this->is_admin === true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

This is called the ternary operator:

```
return $this->has_admin_acces() ? 'Admin' : "Standard";
```

It's simply a shortcut method of doing this:

```
if ($this->has_admin_acces()) {
    return 'Admin';
} else {
    return 'Standard';
}
```

The method call returns 'Standard' in your example because the class defaults access to false, and nothing else changes it:

```
private $is_admin = false;
```

Comment: Oh I see the === is to compare . So I should change it to = , so it will change the value to admin right?

Comment: No! Then you'll be elevating every user to admin just by asking if they're an admin. If your desire is to actually *change* the user's admin status, you should make a new appropriately-named method for it, like `make_admin()` or similar.

Comment: Note, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted -- returning 'Standard' is what it *should* do.

Comment: Oh I see,  public function make_admin() {
  return $this->is_admin=true;
}

Comment: Note the `return` isn't needed, you can just do `public function make_admin() { $this->is_admin = true; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Demo https://ideone.com/CFcs1q

```
<?php

class User {

    private $is_admin = true;

    private function has_admin_acces(){
       if ($this->is_admin === true) {
         return true;
       } else {
        return false;
       }
    }


    public function acces_level() {
      return $this->has_admin_acces()  ? 'Admin': "Standard";
    }

}

$user= new User();
echo $user->acces_level();
```

This is a shorthand If / Else

```
$this->has_admin_acces()  ? 'Admin': "Standard";
```

it is equivalent to writing

```
if($this->has_admin_acces()){
    return 'Admin';
}else{
    return 'Standard';
}
```

If you want to set the user level you can do it this way

```
<?php

class User {

    private $is_admin = true;


    public function set_user($user = false){

        if($user === true){
            $this->is_admin = true;
        }else{
            $this->is_admin = false;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    private function has_admin_acces(){
       if ($this->is_admin === true) {
         return true;
       } else {
        return false;
       }
    }


    public function acces_level() {
      return $this->has_admin_acces()  ? 'Admin': "Standard";
    }

}

$user= new User();
echo $user->set_user(false)->acces_level(); // Standard
echo $user->set_user(true)->acces_level(); // Admin
echo $user->set_user()->acces_level(); // Standard
```